# Creating list of dragables executing function with ids of both on drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a series of HTML spans, such as:

```
<span class="dragable" id="Apple">
<span class="dragable" id="Banana">
<span class="dragable" id="Carrot">
```

...etc. My goal is to make each span dragable onto any other span. Upon this occurring, a JavaScript function will be invoked, which will somehow determine the ID of both the dragged and dropped elements, and then log them to the console (for debugging purposes of course)

Making these spans dragable is simple, but I'm not sure how to go out about passing the IDs to JavaScript. I've seen some tutorials on passing the IDs through events, but not any clear ones.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI. It provides drag and drop just like you need it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $output = $('#output');
  $(".draggable").draggable({revert: true}).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $dragged = $(ui.draggable[0]);
      $output.text($dragged.attr('id') + " was dropped on " + $(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<span class="draggable" id="Apple"></span>
<span class="draggable" id="Banana"></span>
<span class="draggable" id="Carrot"></span>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Have a closer look to the docs of [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) to see full functionality.

Comment: Great answer! Helped me ! Just wondering, how can it be adjusted so that the tip of the corner gets considered too? Is that adjustable at all ?

Comment: I think it's not possible by just using droppable. You could check intersections between two rectangles. Check the [events](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) example from draggable to see how to execute when dropping the draggable object anywhere. But anyway, you have to check manually, if they overlap.

Comment: Yeah I thought of using the top and left from the dropped event and then calculate all other elements positions and see if they match up, thanks !